# prevent event dblclick after handing mousedown

Tags: javascript, mouse

After receiving a mousedown event and handling it (called event.preventDefault()), I don't want to receive a double click event (the second click after the first one handled).

Is there a standard way to do this? I could record the time of the last click and avoid doubleclicks below certain delay but I'd like to know if there's some straighter way.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell its a doubleclick thats happened on the `mousedown` event if `event.detail=2`. You can just check for that within your existing mousedown handler and deal with it accordingly.

```js
function handler(e){
  if(e.detail==1){
    //standard mousedown logic
    console.log("Single Click")
  }else{
    //maybe do nothing in your case?
    console.log("Double Click")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="handler(event)">Click me</button>
```